# Error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: <... omitted ...>ecorated

Tags: r, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, rstudio

Im coding my CNN and i get this Graph execution error while running history... Please see attached.

```
[Error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
<... omitted ...>ecorated
update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\PYTHON~2\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn
return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\PYTHON~2\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\base_metric.py", line 691, in update_state
matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\PYTHON~2\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\metrics.py", line 3636, in categorical_accuracy
return metrics_utils.sparse_categorical_matches(
File "C:\PROGRA~1\PYTHON~2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 964, in sparse_categorical_matches
y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
Node: 'ArgMax_1'
Reduction axis -1 is empty in shape [100,0]
[[{{node ArgMax_1}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1042]
See `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details]
```

[image: Link]

Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Please don't share your code through a screen capture. We have no idea of what you are doing and no idea about your input, so we can't help you.